# Is 'Creative' a noun or adj in this phase : Creative in thinking of ways to make money?

Tags: grammar

Is 'Creative' a noun or adj in this phrase:

> Creative in thinking of ways to make money?

There is a definition for "enterprising": Creative in thinking of ways to make money. As a noun, 'Creative' is a person with creativity. I don't think it fits the sentence, because enterprising is an adjective and also is not a person. But if it is an adjective, the phrase seems not make sense grammatically. I'm rarely seeing 'creative in' in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is marketing lingo:

*Creative in thinking of ways to make money?*

[Are you] Creative in thinking of ways to make money?

You can be creative in any field of endeavor.

Sentences are often shortened. A famous one is: Got Milk?

creative is an adjective. The noun is creativity.

Very often the pronouns or auxiliary verbs are left off. This reflects common speech patterns.

Answer (score 0):

"He is creative (in thinking of ways to make money)" uses the adjective *creative* as a predicate adjective. You will find one of many discussions of the concept in

> [Your Dictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/predicate-adjective.html)
>
> When you describe the subject of a sentence with an adjective, you're using a predicate adjective. Like other adjectives, predicate adjectives modify nouns — but they're used a little bit differently in the sentence.

In the case of *enterprising*, as has been commented, "He is enterprising" uses the participial adjective *enterprising* as a predicate adjective.